# Pyspark error - Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found on AWS EMR

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Even though the compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar is present in spark/jars, I am unable to get rid of this error.

Here is what i am trying to do:

Create a df schema from a list of column names

```
def get_schema(column_names):
    schema = StructType([StructField(c, StringType(), True) for c in column_names.split("|")])
    return schema
```

Then I am trying to use the schema in a DF, where in_schema is the df schema

```
if len(df.take(1)) != 0:
    df = spark.createDataFrame(df, in_schema)
```

Is there anything else that I am missing here?

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o45.partitions.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Compression codec com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found.
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.configure(TextInputFormat.java:45)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:132)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was resolved by using the below properties.

```
spark.executor.extraClassPath /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*

spark.driver.extraClassPath /etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*
```

Comment: This solution worked for me too, using EMR version 6.0.0.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works with EMR 6.7.0